# Change nativescript application-wide CSS file dynamically

Tags: nativescript

I need to change the application-wide CSS file dynamically for a nativescript app. ( Not the page css file, the application css file)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `app.css` file programmatically. In your app.js / app.ts file, add something like:

```
import application = require("application");
application.cssFile = "style.css";

application.start({ moduleName: "main-page" });
```

Import application in other places of your application and try to modify `cssFile` property.

See

- https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#application-wide-css